# why I can't access my files inside gitlab directory

Tags: git, gitlab

I am in the process of migrating to gitlab from github. and after loggin with my github credentials and creating a project. I uploaded an application; however, I can't access the *.java files inside the directory in the image below.
http://pctechtips.org/apps/gitlab_directory.PNG
everything else is there, but *.java files inside that directory. this is the first time working with gitlab. "randomquotes" is a directory inside my android app, but for I can't open it. Any suggestions welcome
thanks

Comment: It appears as if 'randomquotes' is a git-submodule. See the hash next to it? This means you have one git project, inside another git project.

Comment: how can I avoid this from happening?.. I cd into the projects directory in local computer, then run the gitlab commands after creating the project on gitlab, when I upload the directory is back as a sub project.. what is the proper way to do this. I"m doing what I've always done with github

Answer (score 1):

You have run the GitLab commands in the parent folder of `randomquotes` instead of within randomquotes.

Since `randomquotes` has its own `.git` subfolder, the parent folder consider it as a nested Git repository, and only records its tree SHA1.

To avoid this, go to the `randomquotes` folder, check the remote, change it, and push.

```
cd /path/to/randomquotes
git remote -v
git remote set-url origin /url/new/GitLab/repo
git push --mirror
```